# MySQL Trigger - Storing a SELECT in a variable

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a trigger in which I want to have a variable that holds an INT I get from a `SELECT`, so I can use it in two IF statements instead of calling the `SELECT` twice. How do you declare/use variables in MySQL triggers?

Answer (score 60):

You can declare local variables in MySQL triggers, with the `DECLARE` syntax.

Here's an example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo;
CREATE TABLE FOO (
  i SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS bar //

CREATE TRIGGER bar AFTER INSERT ON foo
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE x INT;
  SET x = NEW.i;
  SET @a = x; -- set user variable outside trigger
END//

DELIMITER ;

SET @a = 0;

SELECT @a; -- returns 0

INSERT INTO foo () VALUES ();

SELECT @a; -- returns 1, the value it got during the trigger
```

When you assign a value to a variable, you must ensure that the query returns only a single value, not a set of rows or a set of columns.  For instance, if your query returns a single value in practice, it's okay but as soon as it returns more than one row, you get "`ERROR 1242: Subquery returns more than 1 row`".

You can use `LIMIT` or `MAX()` to make sure that the local variable is set to a single value.

```
CREATE TRIGGER bar AFTER INSERT ON foo
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE x INT;
  SET x = (SELECT age FROM users WHERE name = 'Bill'); 
  -- ERROR 1242 if more than one row with 'Bill'
END//

CREATE TRIGGER bar AFTER INSERT ON foo
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE x INT;
  SET x = (SELECT MAX(age) FROM users WHERE name = 'Bill');
  -- OK even when more than one row with 'Bill'
END//
```

Comment: Is it possible to store a result set in a variable, or do you have to issue separate queries?

Comment: No, a variable can store only a single value.  You must declare an SQL data type for the variable, just like for a column of a table.  There is no data type in MySQL that stores a result set.

Comment: It's a shame the user is not around to accept this answer, because it is the right one.

Comment: I have a doubt. When the tirgger is created, the _select_ is called that time or when the insert happens?

Comment: @Akash The query in the trigger body is executed when the trigger executes, not when the trigger is defined. You can test this by assigning the result of the query to a session variable (prefixed with `@`) so the variable will have the value after the insert is done. Then you can check what value is in your session variable.

Comment: @BillKarwin Dear, I am using ```SET NEW.DoctorName = (select current_user())``` but it shows me the value in DoctorName to the user that creates the trigger.

Comment: @Akash, Use the `USER()` function, not `CURRENT_USER()`. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user: "*Triggers and events have no option to define the SQL SECURITY characteristic, so for these objects, CURRENT_USER() returns the account for the user who defined the object. To return the invoker, use USER() or SESSION_USER().*"

Comment: Dear @BillKarwin Thank you so much.

Answer (score 8):

```
CREATE TRIGGER clearcamcdr AFTER INSERT ON `asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET @INC = (SELECT sip_inc FROM trunks LIMIT 1);
  IF NEW.billsec >1 AND NEW.channel LIKE @INC 
    AND NEW.dstchannel NOT LIKE "" 
  THEN
    insert into `asteriskcdrdb`.`filtre` (id_appel,date_appel,source,destinataire,duree,sens,commentaire,suivi) 
      values (NEW.id,NEW.calldate,NEW.src,NEW.dstchannel,NEW.billsec,"entrant","",""); 
  END IF;
END$$
```

Dont try this @ home

Answer (score 6):

```
`CREATE TRIGGER `category_before_ins_tr` BEFORE INSERT ON `category`
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    **SET @tableId= (SELECT id FROM dummy LIMIT 1);**

END;`;
```

Comment: I edited this for formatting, so you might want to check to make sure it's still syntactically correct.

Answer (score 5):

I'm posting this solution because I had a hard time finding what I needed.  This post got me close enough (+1 for that thank you), and here is the final solution for **rearranging column data before insert if the data matches a test**.

Note: this is from a *legacy project* I inherited where:

1. The Unique Key is a composite of `rridprefix` + `rrid`
2. Before I took over there was no constraint preventing duplicate unique keys
3. We needed to combine two tables (one full of duplicates) into the main table which now has the constraint on the composite key (so merging fails because the gaining table won't allow the duplicates from the unclean table)
4. `on duplicate key` is less than ideal because the columns are too numerous and may change

**Anyway, here is the trigger that puts any duplicate keys into a legacy column while allowing us to store the legacy, bad data (and not trigger the gaining tables composite, unique key)**.

```
BEGIN
  -- prevent duplicate composite keys when merging in archive to main
  SET @EXIST_COMPOSITE_KEY = (SELECT count(*) FROM patientrecords where rridprefix = NEW.rridprefix and rrid = NEW.rrid);

  -- if the composite key to be introduced during merge exists, rearrange the data for insert
  IF @EXIST_COMPOSITE_KEY > 0
  THEN

    -- set the incoming column data this way (if composite key exists)

    -- the legacy duplicate rrid field will help us keep the bad data
    SET NEW.legacyduperrid = NEW.rrid;

    -- allow the following block to set the new rrid appropriately
    SET NEW.rrid = null;

  END IF;

  -- legacy code tried set the rrid (race condition), now the db does it
  SET NEW.rrid = (
    SELECT if(NEW.rrid is null and NEW.legacyduperrid is null, IFNULL(MAX(rrid), 0) + 1, NEW.rrid)
    FROM patientrecords
    WHERE rridprefix  = NEW.rridprefix
  );
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can just include the SELECT statement in the SQL that's invoking the trigger, so its passed in as one of the columns in the trigger row(s). As long as you're certain it will infallibly return only one row (hence one value). (And, of course, it must not return a value that interacts with the logic in the trigger, but that's true in any case.)

Answer (score 1):

As far I think I understood your question
I believe that u can simply declare your variable inside "DECLARE"
and then after the "begin" u can use 'select into " you variable" ' statement.
the code would look like this:

```
DECLARE
YourVar  varchar(50);
begin 
select ID into YourVar  from table
where ...
```

Comment: This will not work in MYSQL, I have try it the same way as you described but it won't load data into var.