# Phpmyadmin create trigger syntax error near 'END'

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a trigger in PhpMyAdmin, and I keep getting the same error everytime I try to create it. The error is:

> **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 5**

I can't seem to get it to work at all, all the questions I've seen about this topic all point to not setting the delimiter as the problem, but mine has already been set. Any help would be nice, I've created a very simple trigger just to test it out, the code is below:

```
DELIMITER ;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `triggerName`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `triggerName` AFTER UPDATE ON `test`
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM `test_2` WHERE `id` = 1
        END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `;` after `END` and at the end of `SELECT`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `triggerName` AFTER UPDATE ON `test`
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM `test_2` WHERE `id` = 1;
        END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: If you want to store selected values, check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/328186/2873538).

Comment: Thanks for the tips, the original trigger wasn't a select, its a longer insert/update with more conditions, I was sure the SQL code inside the trigger was working, just unsure on why it was throwing an error at 'END' thanks for the help though!

Comment: This is not correct. I will write the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The last END of the trigger body should use the DELIMITER you declared, like so: `END$$`

Each statement within BEGIN and END can (must) then be ended with `;` to not tell MySQL that your TRIGGER statement has ended.

So end line 7 with `;` and remove the space between `END` and `$$` on line 8.