# How can I create a session-relative MySQL global variable to use in a trigger?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I am trying to create **logging tables** for my web-based systems.
I want to keep track of **insert, updates and deletes** on each table into its respective log table using MySQL triggers, but I want to **add** the aplication  **logged user** (one who logs using PHP SESSION) who is performing those action in the log table. I was thinking on creating a **session-relative MySQL global variable** so I can access it in the **trigger** and save it.
but how can I create such a variable ?
any help or sugestion will be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: just use USER() (MySQL logged in user) you dont need global variable(s)

Comment: USER() will not give the MySQL user? I was talking about the application user, one looged with PHP SESSION

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Trigger - Storing a SELECT in a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324605/mysql-trigger-storing-a-select-in-a-variable)

Comment: Use can use a php query like `SET @username = 'Jahleel'` and in the trigger code you should be  able to use the variable @username...  please check out "MySQL Trigger - Storing a SELECT in a variable"

Comment: Thanks Raymon Nijland, it worked